# Assigning translateY value by a string

Tags: javascript

I'm using some JavaScript to keep my sidebar fixed when user scrolls the page and when he reached to nearly bottom of the page, then make the sidebar `position: static`. This is the code:

```
<script>

    window.onscroll = function() {
var px = window.scrollY;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar");
var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;
var poht = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
var poht2 = poht - 1300;

if(px < poht2){

  if(px > 1700)    
      {x[0].style.position="fixed";x[0].style.transform="translateY(-1700px)";}

  if(px < 1680){
       if(x[0].style.position=="fixed")   
         {x[0].style.position="static";x[0].style.transform="translateY(20px)";}
   }
}
       // Problem occurs here

pos2 = -1 * 2300 - poht2;
pos2 = pos2 + "px";

else {x[0].style.position="static";x[0].style.transform="translateY(pos2)";}

}
</script>
```

At the last line (I mean `else`) when I want to calculate a value and assign it to `translateY()`, it's not working. What is the right form for doing that?

Thanks.

Comment: why not use absolute, bottom: 0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string concatenation or template literal

```
x[0].style.transform = "translateY(" + pos2 + ")"
```

```
x[0].style.transform = `translateY(${pos2})`
```